# Программирование Android-приложений на Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

Нужно программировать Андроид-приложения на ОС Убунту.
Я установил Эклипс, Андроид СДК и прочей фигни.
Но при компиляции лезет такое окно:

[image]

Comment: Зачетное окно, особенно фотки снизу и с правой стороны :)

Comment: эклипс и прочие сдк желательно размещать в папках, где нет кириллицы в пути к ним, бывали с этим проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

У вас нет прав запуска/доступа к ADB (Android Debug Bridge), попробуйте выполнить:

```
su chmod 777 /home/romanzi/Рабочий стол/android-sdk-linux/tools/*
su chmod 777 /home/romanzi/Рабочий стол/android-sdk-linux/platforms-tools/*
```